# How to prevent duplicate some attributes when query

Tags: sql

I have two table. For example : `Teacher(name, classCode)` and `ClassSession(classCode, session, name)`.

and the query is : find all teacher that teaches subject A.

For example:

```
Teacher
peter 1
Mary 2

ClassSession
1 summer database
1 spring database
...
```

And I query like this :

```
select * from teacher,ClassSession
where Teacher.classCode = ClassSession.classCode
```

And the result will be:

```
Peter 1 summer database
Peter 1 spring database
```

the result is duplicate attribute teacher name, because one subject can teach in multisessions. So, my question is : How can I query to avoid this duplicate. the result should only be `Peter` name.

```
Peter 1
```

Comment: you only want the name `peter` to come back?

Comment: yes. or moreover, just all attributes in table Teacher

Comment: Did you test DISTINCT keyword for your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct tch.*
from teacher tch ,ClassSession cls
where Tch.classCode = Cls.classCode
```

However, I would recommend the following:

Use proper join syntax..

```
select distinct tch.*
from teacher tch 
join ClassSession cls on Tch.classCode = Cls.classCode
```

Also, not sure why you ever need to join two tables, since you are not pulling any information from the ClassCode table.   If you need the second table for the class name, do the following:

```
select distinct tch.*,cls.Name
from teacher tch 
join ClassSession cls on Tch.classCode = Cls.classCode
```

Comment: Implicit syntax should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding this:

```
find all teacher that teaches subject A
```

the query should be this:

```
select * from teacher,ClassSession
where Teacher.classCode = ClassSession.classCode  
and ClassSession.classCode = 'A';
```

because all your original query is returning is everywhere the `teacher.classCode` matches any given `classCode`.

Now in terms of removing the duplicate `Peter` entries that one becomes a bit more difficult, so what you most likely want to do is this:

```
    select ClassSession.* from teacher,ClassSession
    where Teacher.classCode = ClassSession.classCode  
    and ClassSession.classCode = 'A'  
    and Teacher.name = 'Peter';
```

now what this does is stops querying the `teacher` table because you already know whom you are looking for and you supply that as part of the where clause.

**After OP update**

```
    select distinct teacher.* from teacher,ClassSession
    where Teacher.classCode = ClassSession.classCode  
    and ClassSession.classCode = 'A';
```

Comment: Implicit syntax should not be used.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO could you please clarify?  it is always beneficial when i can learn something.

Comment: [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)